# Continuity of an integral w.r.t. a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $f(x,t)\in L^\infty(\Omega\times (0,T))$ $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and extend $f$ to zero oustide this domain.
Consider for $h>0$ the integral
$$F_h(t):= \int_\Omega \frac{f(x,t+h)-f(x,t)}{h}$$
By Fubini's theorem the integral exists for almost every $t\in(0,T)$.
I want to know/show whether this integral is continuous in $h$. Note that the domain of integration is not $\Omega \times (0,T)$

What have I tried so far: I chose a sequence $h_n\to h$ and tried to estimate
$$|F_h(t)-F_{h_n}(t)|\leq \int_\Omega |\frac{f(x,t+h)-f(x,t)}{h} - \frac{f(x,t+h_n)-f(x,t)}{h_n}|$$
Then I estimated the integrand
$$|\frac{f(x,t+h)-f(x,t)}{h} - \frac{f(x,t+h_n)-f(x,t)}{h_n}|\leq |f(x,t)/h_n-f(x,t)/h| + |f(x,t+h)/h-f(x,t+h_n)/h_n|$$

Probably not the best estimate. The problem I find in any attempt i tried is that in general $|f(x,t+h)-f(x,t+h_n)|$ does not need converge to zero since $f$ is not continuous.
Think of $h=1, t=0, h_n<1$ and $f=0$ on $[0,1)$ and $f(1)=1$. Of course this occurs in one single point. Can this occur on a non Null set? Why or Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a counterexample without even thinking about the $x$ dependence - if $f$ does not depend on $x$, then the integral collapses to $\mu(\Omega)$ and you're left with the question of whether the finite difference quotients of a function in $L^{\infty}((0,T))$ are continuous.

Consider $f(x,t) = \chi_{\{t \ge 1/2\}}$, $\chi$ the characteristic function. Then for every $t \in (0,1/2)$ we have

$$ F_h (t) = \mu(\Omega) \frac{1}{h} \chi_{\{ h \ge 1/2 - t \}} $$

which is piecewise continuous but jumps from $0$ to $\mu(\Omega) \frac{2}{1-2t}>0$ at $h=\frac{1}{2} - t$; so $F_h(t)$ is not continuous in $h$ (and nor is any function equal to it almost everywhere).

Comment: To sum things up: For (almost) (if I choose another representative) every $t\in(0,1/2)$ there is an $h$ such that $F_h(t)$ is not continuous in $h$, right? What puzzles me is that I found a paper where it is claimed (without proof) that $F_h(t)$ is continuous in $h$

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: right. Are you sure there aren't more hypotheses on $f$ in the paper?

Comment: Sorry, it is not claimed that $F$ is continuous in $h$ but it is used :) $f$ is the solution of an pde and has the regularity $f\in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$. So it is not essentially more than we have here. btw: the link to the paper is this: http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/RSMUP/RSMUP_1997__98_/RSMUP_1997__98__253_0/RSMUP_1997__98__253_0.pdf and i think the continuity after equation (3.1') when exploiting the separability of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: it seems to be that the weak solutions in this paper are actually $H^1((0,T)\times\Omega)$?

Comment: Thats' what i thought too, but the space presented there does only contain the first $n$ derivatives, i.e. the derivatives in space. Consider the definition of $W^{1,0}_2$ and footnote (1).

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: oh, you're right. I don't follow the last part you referenced - how does one argue that the exceptional set is independent of $\lambda, \psi$? Perhaps the requirement on $u_\lambda$ is not quite continuous, but I dunno... perhaps there is some regularity theory for equations of this type they are assuming?

Comment: the idea should be the the following (I neglect the terms of the spatial integral and only show indepence of $\psi$): By fundamental theorem of calculus of variations we get that $F_{\lambda,\psi}(t)=\int_K \partial_t u_\lambda \psi + \text{rest}=0$  for a.e $t$. Where the exceptional set depends on $\psi$ and $\lambda$, denote it by $N_{\psi,\lambda}$.  Since $H^¹_0(K)$ is separable, we can choose a dense countable familiy of function $\mathcal{F}$. By continuity of $F$ in $\psi$ and density of $\mathcal{F}$ the biggest exceptional set is $N=\bigcup_{\psi \in \mathcal{F}} N_{\psi,\lambda}$.

Comment: and this set is a countable union of sets of measure zero, hence has measure zero. Since any function can be approximated functions out of $\mathcal{F}$ we won't increase the set of exceptional points. However as we discussed above. This idea does not work for the independence of $\lambda$ .